# Get object from array with largest price

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hi how to get object with largest Price using javascript:

I have this code but it doesn't work good

```
var array = [{Name: "blue",Price: 20},{Name: "red",Price: 10},{Name: "green",Price: 30}];
var biggestNumber = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    var item = array[i]
  if(biggestNumber < item.Price) {
    biggestNumber = item;
  }
}
console.log(biggestNumber);
```

Comment: I would suggest you to either use **Array.reduce** or **Array.sort** to accomplish such. Both examples: https://jsfiddle.net/63L9z07a/ . Reduce is more efficient.

Comment: `if (biggestNumber.Price < item.Price) {...` You're storing the whole object, not just the number. And initialize `biggestNumber` with an object that has a `Price`.

Comment: If this user is having difficulty with a traditional approach, do these answerers using built in functional constructs and no explanation think their solution will be understood? Are we just showing off?

Comment: Well pointed out @squint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classic approach with [`for` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).

This proposal takes the first element as temporary result and checks all following objects of the array with the result. If a greater `Price` is found, then `result` is changed to the actual element.

```js
var array = [{ Name: "blue", Price: 20 }, { Name: "red", Price: 10 }, { Name: "green", Price: 30 }],
    result = array[0],                   // take the first element
    i;

for (i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {     // iterate from the second on
    if (array[i].Price > result.Price) { // check price, if a greater price found
        result = array[i];               // replace result with actual object
    }
}

console.log(result);
```

Or you could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and return the result of the check inside of the callback.

```js
var array = [{ Name: "blue", Price: 20 }, { Name: "red", Price: 10 }, { Name: "green", Price: 30 }],
    result = array.reduce(function (a, b) {
        return a.Price > b.Price ? a : b;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

The same as above with ES6

```js
var array = [{ Name: "blue", Price: 20 }, { Name: "red", Price: 10 }, { Name: "green", Price: 30 }],
    result = array.reduce((a, b) => a.Price > b.Price ? a : b, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
let highestPrice = Math.max.apply(null, array.map(e => e.Price));
let item = array.find(e => e.Price === highestPrice);
```

Comment: Clever use of apply, well done. Would be nice to add a brief explanation for the OP though.

Comment: You could also do `Math.max.call(null, ...array.map(e => e.Price));`. With es6, anything is possible :p

Comment: Not very optimised: creating a new array just to find the max then looping through the array to find that max! Such a waste!

Comment: @Bwaxxlo: Then you don't need `.call()`. `Math.max(...array.map(/**/))`

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir depends whether you care about readability or optimizations. Unless you're coding for a constrained system, I always go for readability. A for-loop, while efficient, doesn't say much about what you are doing. Good code should make it's intentions clear.

Comment: basically you iterates 2 times, where only one iteration, despite of `for`, `forEach`, `reduce`, is enough to find the max price object.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var array = [{Name: "blue",Price: 20},{Name: "red",Price: 10},{Name: "green",Price: 30}];

var maxIndex = 0;                             // assume the max is at 0
for(var i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {       // for the rest of the objects in the array
  if(array[i].Price > array[maxIndex].Price)  // if the current object is bigger than the assumed max
    maxIndex = i;                             // then this current object's index is the new maxIndex
}

var maxObject = array[maxIndex];              // max object is the object at maxIndex
console.log(maxObject);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to "reduce" your entire array into a single value: the object with the largest price.

```
var itemWithHighestPrice = array.reduce(function(highest, item, index) {
    if (index === 0 || item.Price > highest.Price) {
        return item;
    }
    return highest;
}, {});
```

Comment: why the last param to `reduce`?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I added it because, despite being optional and defaulting to the first item in the array, calling `reduce` without without a default parameter will throw an error. So that's just there in case of an empty array.

Comment: It won't throw an error if it's not use and in this case you're not accessing it due to the `if (index === 0 || )` test!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir: It throws an error if the `array` is empty. `[].reduce((x)=>x) // TypeError` So it's not a bad idea to include it.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir it does throw `Uncaught TypeError: Reduce of empty array with no initial value`, you can try it with `[].reduce(function(acc, item) {})`

Comment: Point proven! I rest my case!

Answer (score 1):

You have to store item.Price in biggestNumber instead of just item.

```
var array = [{Name: "blue",Price: 20},{Name: "red",Price: 10},{Name: "green",Price: 30}];
var biggestNumber = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    var item = array[i]
  if(biggestNumber < item.Price) {
    biggestNumber = item.Price;
  }
}
console.log(biggestNumber);
```

Comment: They want the result to be an object.

Comment: Then they'll need an other approach, biggestNumber is defined as an number in the beginning not an object.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var array = [{Name: "blue",Price: 20},{Name: "red",Price: 10},{Name: "green",Price: 30}];
var biggestNumber = {Price:0};
array.forEach(function(obj){
if(obj.Price>biggestNumber.Price)
   biggestNumber=obj;
});
console.log(biggestNumber);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:**

Your problem is that you are storing the whole `item` object in your `highestPrice` variable, then you try to compare a `Number` with an `object`.

**Solution:**

You should store only the `item.Price` in your `highestPrice` variable and compare `Price` values, edit your code like this:

```
var biggestNumber = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  var item = array[i];
  if (biggestNumber < item.Price) {
    biggestNumber = item.Price;
  }
}
```

**Working snippet:**

```js
var array = [{
  Name: "blue",
  Price: 20
}, {
  Name: "red",
  Price: 10
}, {
  Name: "green",
  Price: 30
}];


var biggestNumber = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  var item = array[i];
  if (biggestNumber < item.Price) {
    biggestNumber = item.Price;
  }
}

console.log(biggestNumber);
```

**Note:**

If you want the whole `item` as result, you just need to compare the two objects `Price` property, update your first code like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    var item = array[i]
  if(biggestNumber.Price < item.Price) {
    biggestNumber = item;
  }
}
```